# SPARQL query in Dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

how do I extract from DBpedia the data on Dutch, French and Italian painters born in the 18th and 19th century?

Comment: What things have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit difficult as not all the artists have birth dates and not every painter has a painter tag. So generally if you want to get 18th and 19th century painter, you can write something like:

```
select distinct *
    where {
    ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Painter.
    ?x dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birth.
    ?x dbpedia-owl:birthPlace ?city.
    ?city dbpedia-owl:country ?country.
 VALUES ?country { dbpedia:Italy dbpedia:Germany dbpedia:Netherlands } 
 FILTER(str(?birth) >= "1700-1-1" && str(?birth) < "1900-1-1") 
}
```

If you want everything about this person `?x` you can just add `?x ?p ?o` before the filter.

Comment: The `filter (?country = ... || ?county = ... || ...)` is pretty verbose.  Any reason not to use `values ?county { dbpedia:Italy dbpedia:Germany dbpedia:Netherlands }`?